# How to get nested level of property class by reflection in .net

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, nested

```
Class A
{
  public B child {get; set;}
}

Class B
{
   public string childProperty {get; set;}
}
```

I am getting all property

```
 var BType = AType.GetType().GetProperty("child");
```

I am able to get "Child" property of A, but how i can get "childProperty" from BType?

Answer (score 1):

You can get `B` type using `BType.PropertyType`:

```
A AType = new A();

var BType = AType.GetType().GetProperty("child");
var childPropertyType = BType.PropertyType.GetProperty("childProperty");
```